# Accessing json values

Tags: python, json

I have loaded the following json this way:

```
url2 = "https://gbfs.capitalbikeshare.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json"
response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
cabi_station_status = json.load(response2)
```

sample output of cabi_station_status:

```
{u'stations': [{u'eightd_has_available_keys': False,
   u'is_installed': 1,
   u'is_renting': 1,
   u'is_returning': 1,
   u'last_reported': 1489309320,
   u'num_bikes_available': 5,
   u'num_bikes_disabled': 0,
   u'num_docks_available': 10,
   u'num_docks_disabled': 0,
   u'station_id': u'1'},
  {u'eightd_has_available_keys': False,
   u'is_installed': 1,
   u'is_renting': 1,
   u'is_returning': 1,
   u'last_reported': 1489309256,
   u'num_bikes_available': 5,
   u'num_bikes_disabled': 0,
   u'num_docks_available': 6,
   u'num_docks_disabled': 0,
   u'station_id': u'2'}
```

I cannot figure out how to access the value of "num_bikes_available" of certain stations.  When I try `cabi_station_status["stations"]["station_id"][1]`

it does not return anything.  Pseudo code for my ideal output would be to get the "num_bikes"available" when "station_id" == 1. and return an integer, in this case, 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for station in cabi_station_status['stations']:
    if station['station_id'] == '1':
        print(station['num_bikes_available'])
```

Comment: That worked!  I was so close with my attempt: 'for key in cabi_station_status(): ]
    if cabi_station_status.get("station_id","") == 1:
        print ["num_bikes_available"'

Answer (score 1):

`cabi_station_status["stations"]` is a list.

You should use a loop to iterate over each station and from each station get `num_bikes_available`.

```
each_station['num_bikes_available']
```

Your solution would look like:

```
for each_station in cabi_station_status["stations"]:
    if each_station['station_id'] == '1':
        return each_station['num_bikes_available']
```

Answer (score 0):

`cabi_station_status["stations"]` is a list; you need to refer to its elements by index, not key.

```
cabi_station_status["stations"][0]["num_bikes_available"]
```

Comment: hmm, so no way to selected num_bikes_available based off of a station_id?  The index is not 1:1 for the stations, ie index 12 = station_id:14 and index 45 = station_id: 52